# PHP to lock XFCE screen

Tags: php

How I can lock my XFCE Linux screen with PHP to lock from console I'm use `xflock4` but when i use `shell_exec()` in PHP script with 777 premisions and my group nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Comment: You probably need to provide an argument to specify the X display, or set the `DISPLAY` environment variable before calling it.

Comment: But how i can do this?

Comment: I can't find documentation on the web for this command, but if it's like most X commands, it would be `xflock4 -display :0.0`

Comment: Just a suggestion I would first test in a terminal to be sure that the command actually works, when you confirm it works use shell_exec.

Comment: Also have a look at this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101806/why-doesnt-my-screen-lock-in-xfce Do you have locker installed?

Comment: @Barmar Comand working in console but not working with PHP script.

Comment: What does the output return when you run the script? Does user which is running php have permission to execute this script?

Comment: @MiljanIlic Are you running the PHP script from the console? If not, it doesn't inherit the `DISPLAY` environment variable from your terminal.

Comment: @VladimirJelovac Premissions of PHP script are 777 and I'm owner. Barmar I'm running scriptfrom browser.

Comment: @MiljanIlic when you are running a script from the browser the user who is running the script is web server usually apache. The user who is running the apache must have permission to run xflock4. You can check who is the user by running this simple script `<?php exec('whoami'); ?>`

Comment: Group that runing script is www-data, but how I can allow that group to run command?